# Google Play automatically "updating" dev version

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing

I am currently observing an issue with the distribution of my app to internal testers. It seems that google play (if automatic updates enabled) automatically updates the dev- version ( distributed through Crashlytics - Beta ) of my app to the store version regardless of the versionCode specified.

```
Store version: versionCode 101 - com.example.package 
Dev version: versionCode 102 - com.example.package
```

In that case the dev version gets "updated" to the store version on a daily basis.

I have observed the issue on Android 6.0 and Android 7.1 so far. All devices are on the latest beta play store- services version.

I have not had those issues before. Is there anyone else experiencing the same thing? If so, I will file a bug with the google play team.